# Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument

Tags: ios, swift

**In Objective-C**

```
CGPDFArrayRef array;
```

**This works fine: Whereas in Swift it should be,**

```
var array:CGPDFArrayRef
```

**But it's giving this error when passes in the next line:**

```
var success = CGPDFScannerPopArray(inScanner, &array)
```

> Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: implicit conversion from 'CGPDFArrayRef' to 'CGPDFArrayRef?' requires a temporary.

Comment: try this `var array: CGPDFArrayRef? = nil`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik: Yes, that is the correct solution.

Comment: @Hemang: Your updated code in the question compiles without problems.

Comment: Yes, corrected. But the actual problem was different.

Comment: thank you @Anbu ... there are times I wonder if the designers of Swift take pleasure in making what was supposed to be a simple language a truly convoluted one. Seriously.  Whomever decided on forcing each of us to deal repeated with optional variables needs to be taking to the principal's office.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by passing the `array` like this:

```
var success = CGPDFScannerPopArray(inScanner, UnsafeMutablePointer(array))
```